# Storing floating points in a stack

Tags: floating-point, mips

I'm trying to store floating point numbers into a stack from register $f1 using the stack pointer.  I always get errors that the address is out of range.  After I do that I want to pop the words out of the stack and print them to the screen.  I am using Mars.  Here is some sample code.

## SAMPLE CODE

```
    li, $t3, 0      # set counter register
l.s $f1, zero       # load floating point 0.00 into $f1
li $sp, 252     # start the stack size
swc1 $f1, ($sp)     # store the floating point as a word in the stack
loop:
addi $sp, $sp, -4   # decrement the stack pointer
swc1 $f1, ($sp)     # store the floating point as a word in the stack   
bgt $sp, $t3, loop  # continue loop until all stack is populated

print to screen after this line

li $t2, 7
li $sp, 252     # start the stack size
lwc1 $f12, ($sp)    # pop from stack
li $v0, 2
syscall
printloop:
addi $sp, $sp, -4   # decrement the stack pointer
lwc1 $f12, ($sp)    # pop from stack
li $v0, 2       
syscall
addi $t2, $t2, -1
bnez $t2, printloop
lw $a0, newline
li $v0, 4
syscall
li $t2, 7
printloop2:
addi $sp, $sp, -4   
lwc1 $f12, ($sp)
li $v0, 2
syscall
addi $t2, $t2, -1
bnez $t2, printloop2
lw $a0, newline
li $v0, 4
syscall
li $t2, 7
printloop3:
addi $sp, $sp, -4   
lwc1 $f12, ($sp)
li $v0, 2
syscall
addi $t2, $t2, -1
bnez $t2, printloop3
lw $a0, newline
li $v0, 4
syscall
li $t2, 7
printloop4:
addi $sp, $sp, -4   
lwc1 $f12, ($sp)
li $v0, 2
syscall
addi $t2, $t2, -1
bnez $t2, printloop4
lw $a0, newline
li $v0, 4
syscall
li $t2, 7
printloop5:
addi $sp, $sp, -4   
lwc1 $f12, ($sp)
li $v0, 2
syscall
addi $t2, $t2, -1
bnez $t2, printloop5
lw $a0, newline
li $v0, 4
syscall
li $t2, 7
printloop6:
addi $sp, $sp, -4   
lwc1 $f12, ($sp)
li $v0, 2
syscall
addi $t2, $t2, -1
bnez $t2, printloop6
lw $a0, newline
li $v0, 4
syscall
li $t2, 7
printloop7:
addi $sp, $sp, -4   
lwc1 $f12, ($sp)
li $v0, 2
syscall
addi $t2, $t2, -1
bnez $t2, printloop7
lw $a0, newline
li $v0, 4
syscall
li $t2, 7   
printloop8:
addi $sp, $sp, -4   
lwc1 $f12, ($sp)
li $v0, 2
syscall
addi $t2, $t2, -1
bnez $t2, printloop8
li $v0, 10
syscall
```

Answer (score 0):

I think your problem is that you setting the stack in the `text` segment.
I'd remove this line

```
li $sp, 252     # start the stack size
```

and change

```
li, $t3, 0
```

to

```
subu $t3, $sp, 252
```

so that you loop until the stack is filled with 64 items